# how to call function after angular grid initilize

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, angularjs, node.js

Please look below scenario
    I have angular grid which is populating some data than i am calling one function(CreateCheckBox) from cellRenderer event which dynamically creating some checkboxes in the angular grid now i want to work with these checkboxes so i am looking any event or something in angular grid which  fire after cellRenderer please help?

```
var columnDefs1 = [
{ field: 'IS_MAPPED', headerName: "", width: 42, 
cellRenderer:   CreateCheckBox, headerCellRenderer: HeaderApproveAll,
cellClass: 'grid-align', cellStyle: { "text-align": "center", "align"
: "center" }, suppressMenu: true },{ field: 'PARAM_DESC', headerName:
getLabel_Header()
["$PARAM_DESCRIPTION$"], width: 352, cellClass: 'grid-left' }];

function CreateCheckBox(params) {
    var chkVal = "chkInner" + cor;
    alarmId = chkVal;
    var chkproperty = '';


if ($scope.gridOptions1.rowData[params.rowIndex]['IS_MAPPED'] == 'TRUE') {
            chkproperty = 'true';
        }
        else {
            chkproperty = 'false';
        }
        var html = '<span style="align:center;"><input type="checkbox" id="' + chkVal + '" name="chkInner"   ng-checked="' + chkproperty + '" ng-click="toggleA()" /></span>';
        var domElement = document.createElement("span");
        domElement.innerHTML = html;

        params.$scope.toggleA = function () {
            var chkVal = "chkInner";
            var data = $scope.gridOptions1.rowData;
            var cnt = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                chkVal = "chkInner" + i;
                if ($('#' + chkVal).prop('checked') == true) {
                    cnt = cnt + 1;
                }
            }

            if (cnt == data.length)
                $('#chkApproveAll').attr('checked', true);
            else
                $('#chkApproveAll').attr('checked', false);

        }
    cor++;
    return domElement;//after dom return html i want to run code
}
```

Comment: It's not possible to help you unless you describe the problem properly, no one knows what and how you use for your grid.

Comment: I agree, question is really unclear.

Comment: i haved added the complete code please look once